# Categorization relationship issue, IDEF1X notation

Tags: data-modeling, entity-relationship

I've sketched up the following logic data model schema:

http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/6260/proj1x.png

The problem is in the section MT payment with the general entity @mt_transac@. I can't establish a categorization relation with the category entity @mt_subscr_rebill@ if it has a relation with @mt_subsrc@.

When I delete that relation it works fine. If I set up a relation between @mt_transac@ and @mt_subscr_rebill@ and then try to set up a relation with @mt_subscr@ it also don't work.

What problem may I have in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the primary key of a category must be the same as that of its superclass. With the indentifying relationship shown, the primary key of the category is not equal to the primary key of the superclass.